# Can I use CSS to insert whitespace between elements?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to evenly space out 3+ DIVs of varying & unknown size.  The solution works perfectly if there's whitespace between the `<div>` tags.  But without it, they're clumped together, understandably.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/af5f1vs3/1/

HTML

```
<div class='a'>
  <div class='b'>I</div><div class='b'>Love</div><div class='b'>Pie</div>
</div>
<div class='a'>
  <div class='b'>I</div> <div class='b'>Love</div> <div class='b'>Pie</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.a {
  text-align: justify;
}
.a::after {
  content:'';
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
.b {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I use a HTML minification tool that collapses whitespace between tags.  In most cases, this is perfect and solves many other problems caused by extraneous whitespace between html tags.  But in this case, it causes a problem.  So, I'm hoping for a CSS-only or HTML-only solution which adds back in whitespace between the elements.

Comment: "But in this case, it causes a problem" --- it's surprising that in your layout you rely on the whitespace between block elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex; justify-content: space-between;` on the container (and erase the pseudo element)

```css
.a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.b {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='a'>
  <div class='b'>I</div>
  <div class='b'>Love</div>
  <div class='b'>Pie</div>
</div>
<div class='a'>
  <div class='b'>I</div><div class='b'>Love</div><div class='b'>Pie</div>
</div>
```

Comment: True, flex gives a simpler and more elegant solution.  Unfortunately, I must support IE9, which means it's not an option for me